# Selenium opening multiple edge tabs after opening the desired site

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

As mentioned in the title, when the tab opens the website loads perfectly. However, around 3 other tabs like msn.com (which I never used) would open as well.

I've tried executing the code in different ways like installing the service on each instance, but with no luck as well.

```
from selenium import webdriver

website = "https://www.adamchoi.co.uk/overs/detailed" 
path = "C:\\bin\\msedgedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Edge(path)
driver.get(website)
```

Comment: Check out your edge browser settings. and disable some setting around default openings of site.

Comment: That's the next thing I've done right after trying different ways of execution.